# Multiple currencies in Magento

Tags: magento, currency

I already have the option to change the currency, but there's another problem. Currently the base currency is set to Euro, which is fine by me, but the client might want to change that. If I change the base currency to RON, the Currency Converter dropdown disappears.

How can I work with another currency than Euro, but still have the option to change the currency in-store? Warning: magento noob :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add currency rate for your new base currency. System - Manage Currency - Rates
Without exchange rates multiple currencies wont be available

Comment: You saved my life! Have been searching for 2 weeks.

Comment: 2 weeks? I hope they don't pay you by the hour.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the base currency. Follow the below steps.

1. From the Admin panel, select **System** > **Configuration**.
2. From the Configuration panel on the left, under General, select the **Currency Setup** tab.
3. Click to expand the **Currency Options** section. Then, do the following:
   In the **Base Currency** list, select the primary currency that is used for store transactions.
   In the **Default Display Currency** list, select the primary currency that is used to display pricing in your store.
   In the **Allowed Currencies** list, select all currencies that are accepted as payment by your store.
4. When finished, click the **Save Config** button.

To enable multiple currency please go through the tutorial at http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/