# Shipping rate currency conversion in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento

Currently have a setup with 2 Magento 1.7.0.2 "websites" one for CAD and one for USD.  You can switch between the sites using a dropdown so that you can purchase in CAD or USD.

When requesting a shipping estimate via Fedex (using in-built Magento module, with a Canadian Fedex account) it displays correctly in CAD on the CAD website, and displays the CAD amount without conversion but with "USD" next to it in the USD website.
(e.g. if it's $10.00 CAD to ship it'll display as $10.00 USD on the USD site, instead of $10.00 x conversion rate).

I thought that if the base currency of the website is set to USD, and I have setup the currencies correctly in the "Manage Currency Rates" section of the admin, then it should convert the returned rate to USD to display in the front-end?

I don't see anywhere in the code where it does the conversion...anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify if the problem is the incorrect quote rate or the text 'USD'/'CAD' being incorrect in the template.

Comment: Hi, the actual quote amount isn't changing.  It shouldn't be the same amount for CAD and USD - if we are on the US website then the CAD amount returned from the quote should be converted to USD via the amount set in the Manage Currencies section of the admin panel (or at least that's my understanding)

Comment: So... the price usually renders in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml which stems from the core currency helper: app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php line 104. You can also call currencyByStore method for the core helper to covert the value directly but this should be done automatic. I'm guessing your configuration of currency for the USD/CAD erroneous pricing store isn't set up fully so please double check:

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/56508/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236159/multiple-currencies-in-magento

Comment: Hi Vlad, in System -> Config -> Currency Setup, the US website has base currency = USD, default display currency = USD, and allowed currency = USD only.  The CAD website has CAD set for these.

If you have the same item in the cart and get a shipping estimate then the dollar amount returned for shipping is the same regardless of the store.  

This shouldn't be, because it is set to 1 CAD = 0.79 USD in System -> Manage Currency Rates.    So if your shipping quote was 10 CAD on the CAD website, you should see 7.90 USD on the US site, but you see 10 USD.

Comment: The customer never needs to switch currency because we are talking about separate websites (not stores).  By switching from the CAD website to the USD website (via a dropdown) you automatically switch currencies because of the setup I just mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72717/discussion-between-vladimir-ramik-and-adam-b).